# Why do browsers' user agent stylesheets use -prefixed CSS properties?

Tags: css, browser

The other day, I was looking at how browsers (I used chrome, but I'm guessing it applies to all) format HTML elements using **user agent stylesheets**.

When using `blockquote`, I found this:

```
blockquote {
 -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
 -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
 -webkit-margin-start: 40px;
 -webkit-margin-end: 40px;
}
```

Look fine. But why couldn't they use something more like this?:

```
blockquote {
 margin-left:/*whatever*/;
 margin-top:/*whatever*/;
 margin-right:/*whatever*/;
 margin-bottom:/*whatever*/;
}
```

This just happened upon me, and I thought it was rather strange.

Comment: Because they can? I always wondered about this too, and kind of assumed it had something to do with box model weirdness. Curious to see what answers you'll get.

Comment: Because they're **user agent stylesheets** (as you so emphasized)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some browsers use CSS rules like this because their specification has not yet been finalised by the W3C, and therefore if they were to leave the prefix off, they would run the risk of the eventual W3C standard format being slightly different, and creating incompatibilities between browsers or between versions of the same browser as they change the format to the standard way of doing things.

This is a particular issue for rules with multiple arguments - the main thing that can go wrong is that the standard ends up having the arguments in a different order:

```
border-radius: 3px 3px 6px 6px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #fff;
```

...etc...

Adding the prefix is their assurance that if the eventual standard turns out to be different from their implementation, nothing will break.

As for the part about `margin-before` instead of `margin-left`, that appears to be because the `-webkit-margin-before` rule isn't an equivalent of `margin-left`, but of `margin:before`, which is a recent proposal aimed at making things work in RTL and vertical writing modes. See this page: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Sep/0625.html It seems to be rather obscure though.

Comment: This doesn't explain why they're using entirely different CSS properties than the 'usual' ones though. It's not `-webkit-margin-left`, it's `-webkit-margin-before`.

Comment: Edited, although I don't think that was the point of the question. The title of the question definitely asks about "-prefixed" CSS properties.

Comment: Right now these properties are simply proprietary to WebKit (*urgh*), and shouldn't be taken as official or endorsed by the working group until they're added to the spec. Vendor prefixes are not just used for experimental versions of official properties; they're also used by vendors to create their own world of properties for themselves to play with or use for various reasons, some of which may or may not eventually be promoted as proposals for addition to the spec. As another, non-WebKit example, Mozilla uses a number of prefixed selectors, properties and values to hack around certain quirks.

Answer (score 1):

To help developers see which elements are the browser defaults.